# Cannot resolve Symbol otl_connect (otl_connect class not including)

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++, otl

I have been trying to connect to mysql using OTL_ODBC. I have included the OTL header file (otlv4.h) in my Visual Studio 2010 Project but when I try to use `otl_connect`, it displays the error "Cannot Resolve Symbol otl_connect", and the `otl_connect` class appears red in colour:

[image]

May I know where I'm doing it wrong?

```
#define OTL_ODBC
#include "otlv4.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  otl_connect db;
}
```

Comment: Including the header is not sufficient. You also need to link to the library. This has been asked and answered many times, but the canonical duplicate is [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I'm really sorry but its not linking error, the otl_connect itself appears **RED** in colour which implies that the class otl_connect doesnt exist.

Comment: Well, then you need to write better questions. :P The title says "Unresolved external symbol", which indicates a linker error. If that's not your problem, don't make that your title. And if your problem is a syntax warning in the IDE, explain that in the post, otherwise people will probably assume it was a compiler error instead

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, this is my second post , I wouldnt make the mistake again :D

Comment: I've voted to close this question as unclear since OP clearly describe a _linking_ error in their title but talk about a compilation error in their comments.

Comment: I have changed the title of the question, Sorry for the inconvenience caused..

Answer (score 0):

`otl_connect` is inside namespace `odbc`. Try `odbc::otl_connect`.

Comment: It doesn't resolve it either. In every other tutorial, it has been written as just otl_connect, i dont know why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same today. The solution was to place #include "otlv4.h" **after** #define OTL_ODBC_MSSQL_2008.